# How to connect a pulled motor from a printer to Breadboard and control with raspberry pi?

Tags: motor, raspberry-pi

I managed to salvage a couple of motors from a worn down old printer, and I'm unsure of how to get about connecting it to a breadboard and then to a Raspberry Pi. I've got a cobbler kit for my Pi that allows me to connect it up to the breadboard. I'm also unsure about what kind of motor it is, DC or Stepper. 
The motor looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQD1O.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: That looks like a DC brush motor.  You'll need a driver and protection circuit, but first you have to figure out the power requirements, either from knowledge of the printer or just experimentally by using increasing numbers flashlight cells and then measuring the current when you get to something reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Cobbler kit to break out your pins, take one of the IO to control a relay. You want to use an external power source to driver the motor. Read up on relays if you're not familiar, but it should be your best bet.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpCF8g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Credit to Scott for mentioning the Pi can't drive the current necessary to turn on the relay. Therefore, I added an npn transistor. Also diode was added for pin safety. From my understanding, the Pi has an accessible 5V from the Cobbler kit? I suggest using this for the collector of the transistor.

I left V1 arbitrary, perform tests to see what voltage needs to turn the motor. That, or find the Datasheet. V1 is where the DC motor will attach to.

Finally, the motor looks like a normal DC motor.

Comment: You can't just connect a mechanical relay to the pi though!

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, but could OP not simply use one of the 8 GPIO that the cobbler kit breaks out?

Comment: Time to learn how to read circuit diagrams!

Also, is there any way I can construct a relay myself or do I have to go out and buy one? If I do, what are the specifications?

Comment: The Pi can't provide enough current to drive a relay-- and without a diode you'll do bad things to the port.  Suggest you add a snubbing diode to your fig.

Comment: Don't people normally have diode protection on the relay coil? @user92466: I wouldn't spend months developing your own relay unless learning relay construction is your primary goal.

Comment: There are many articles on relays to read about; just google and read through them and you'll be able to figure out how to wire it up using one of your GPIO pins.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Thanks for explaining; perhaps an npn transistor would suffice? I'll add this and a diode to the diagram.

Comment: Yup, npn should do fine (unless, of course, its for some kind of huge relay)

Comment: You could also just drive the motor through a power npn

Comment: This is all very confusing, isn't there a simpler way of wiring one up? Or maybe I'm just not experienced enough

Comment: If the above seems confusing, you have some research to do. Try Googling and researching the following: H-bridges (full and half), npn transistors (power and normal) and snubbing diodes. After learning these, you will probably understand what to do.

Comment: Alright, also if you look at the imgur picture, the two wires that run out of the motor lead up into one white thing. I'm unsure of how to connect that to the breadboard.

Comment: Snip it; strip it; profit.

Comment: @user92466: The "one white thing" is probably just a JST PH connector (or similar), you can buy the socket that matches it but, as Nick says, it may well be easier for you to cut it off and solder the stranded leads direct to 0.1" header pins or to short bits of solid wire to poke into your breadboard. (or to solder them directly to the relay contacts)

Comment: Any reason for using 2N3904 NPN transistor? Can I replace the same thing with 2N7000?